# Rails if statement for date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a brain fart.
I need an if statement that if a date has been selected use that selection if not then use Todays date (hardcoded).
I can't remember if this should be in the view where the date_field is or if this needs to be in the controller or model.

Form code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sinDate, "Down Since", class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= f.date_field :sinDate, class: "form-control" %>
      <p><small>This is optional, use if the down date was before today.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
<%= f.date_field :sinDate, as: :date, 
    value: (f.object || Date.Today).try(:strftime,"%m/%d/%Y"), 
    class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: So that didn't work as if I don't select a date it just doesn't put a date. There was a typo in yours where the : needed to be next to sinDate not space. But I appreciate it, still trying to figure it out.